# Which is the highest recorded power level in Nanatsu no Taizai?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I was reading the Nanatsu no Taizai wikia and I saw there Chandler's power level is listed to be 173,000 , which is over Meliodas' power level of 142,000 , which I thought to be the highest.

Which is the highest recorded power level in Nanatsu no Taizai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the wiki's page on [Balor's Magical Eye](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Balor's_Magical_Eye), the highest **known-for-certain** power level recorded in Nanatsu no Taizai is Ludociel's impressive 201 000 (*Chapter 286, page 14*). However, we know that Mael has a 200 000+ power level (*Chapter 278, page 12*). As this is relatively vague, Mael may or may not have a numerically higher power level than Ludociel.

Since Mael has often been described as the strongest Archangel in-universe, it is almost certain that his actual power level goes beyond 201 000. Alas, since it has never been recorded precisely, we cannot actually confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

SPOILERS:

The highest power level we have been given is probably infinite when MERLIN awakens the power of MOTHER CHAOS inside of King Arthur after the demon king was defeated. Now, mother chaos is essentially the creator of the goddess, the demon king, and in turn made all the other races.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. Could you [edit] and mention the chapter/episode where this is shown?